# No display after resume from suspend after fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.1, Nvidia 515.65.01 and kernel 5.15.0-48-generic on Lenovo Extreme Gen5

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 22.04, thinkpad, resume

The Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 5 laptop v1.08 BIOS suspends successfully after closing the lid and appears to resume when opening the lid. However, no video is displayed. Instead, the LCD screen appears backlit, but black. I have tried to troubleshoot using all the Nvidia driver versions 470, 510 and 515. In addition, I have tried X.Org X server Nouveau combined with disabling Wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf. I have also tried to disable the Nvidia suspend, hibernate, and resume services, all without the success of remediating the issue. I have also toggled Linux S3 Sleep in the BIOS settings to no avail. I have tried this all with the latest generally available kernel and the developer-enabled optional kernel below.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Specs:

```
Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 5
```

```
NVIDIA Corporation GA103M [GeForce RTX 3080 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
```

```
Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
```

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
```

```
Linux 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.65.01  Wed Jul 20 14:00:58 UTC 2022
```

```
$nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P3    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4822      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
[s2idle]
```

```
$dmidecode -s bios-version
N3JET24W (1.08 )
```

```
$dmesg
[   70.088474] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from a5:e2:90:13:cf:06 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   72.602167] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   72.760707] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[   72.764050] Filesystems sync: 0.003 seconds
[   73.035394] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[   73.040015] OOM killer disabled.
[   73.040019] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[   73.041748] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[   74.705679] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  111.351101] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  112.420887] nvme nvme0: 20/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[  112.437817] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_62.0.3.bin version 62.0 submission:enabled
[  112.437823] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC SLPC: enabled
[  112.437825] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9 authenticated:yes
[  112.438708] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC RC: enabled
[  112.940361] OOM killer enabled.
[  112.940368] Restarting tasks ...
[  112.941913] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e1-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[  112.945309] done.
[  112.955862] thermal thermal_zone10: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[  113.010296] PM: suspend exit
[  113.863611] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  117.374757] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with a5:e2:90:13:cf:06
[  117.380684] wlp0s20f3: send auth to a5:e2:90:13:cf:06 (try 1/3)
[  117.455125] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
[  117.457852] wlp0s20f3: associate with a5:e2:90:13:cf:06 (try 1/3)
[  117.460849] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from a5:e2:90:13:cf:06 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=4)
[  117.467092] wlp0s20f3: associated
[  117.522287] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
[  121.535978] kauditd_printk_skb: 3 callbacks suppressed
[  121.535980] audit: type=1400 audit(1663205710.438:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/16778/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3829 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  121.535985] audit: type=1400 audit(1663205710.438:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/16778/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3829 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  121.822539] audit: type=1400 audit(1663205710.722:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/16778/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3895 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  121.822545] audit: type=1400 audit(1663205710.722:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/16778/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3895 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  128.010199] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:00:1d.0
[  128.010209] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Requester ID)
[  128.010210] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:   device [8086:51b0] error status/mask=00100000/00004000
[  128.010211] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0:    [20] UnsupReq               (First)
[  128.010213] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER:   TLP Header: 34000000 20000052 00000000 00000000
[  128.010268] thunderbolt 0000:22:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
[  128.010277] xhci_hcd 0000:56:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
[  128.010286] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: device recovery failed
```

```
$cat /var/log/syslog
systemd-sleep[3653]: System returned from sleep state.
bluetoothd[1272]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
kernel: [  113.010296] PM: suspend exit
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:0
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
logger[3743]: Sep 14 21:33:02 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
suspend: nvidia-resume.service
systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1706
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3840x2400"x0.0  592.56  3840 3888 3920 4000  2400 2403 2409 2469 +hsync -vsync (148.1 kHz eP)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1706
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3840x2400"x0.0  592.56  3840 3888 3920 4000  2400 2403 2409 2469 +hsync -vsync (148.1 kHz eP)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2670.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1675]: (II) NVIDIA(G0): Setting mode "NULL"
```

Comment: Where comes the 5.15.0-48 kernel from, when the current kernel is 5.15.0-47? Did you enable the `proposed` repo?

Comment: I enabled pre-release updates (jammy proposed) to get this kernel. I was hoping a newer kernel would resolve my issue. Ultimately switching the graphics device in the BIOS to discrete resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "discrete graphics" mode in the BIOS under Config -> Display -> Graphics Device remediated the issue.

Comment: First of all, I want to confirm that this is an issue on the Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 5. Besides switching to "discrete graphics" mode, the default Ubuntu installation uses the open-source nouveau driver which just [does not support the RTX 3080 Ti yet](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/FeatureMatrix.html) so I had to manually switch to a sufficiently recent version of the proprietary Nvidia driver. According to [Nvidia's driver search](https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce/drivers/), at least driver version 510.54 seems to be required but newer versions are available.